# Neovim highlight syntax region inside typescript tagged template literal

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, filetype-javascript

I am having trouble fixing a syntax plugin for Vim.  I've [found a bug](https://github.com/cdata/vim-tagged-template/issues/4) in a plugin that has not been touched in a fair amount of time. I want to address it myself but I believe I am lacking in a lot of knowledge surrounding the built in syntax rules in vim/neovim. The plugin's job is to syntax highlight a [javascript tagged template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with another filetype syntax. What I want to fix is the plugin's behavior inside a Typescript file.

Essentially there is a piece of syntax that works in Javascript but not in Typescript. Ive used the great plugin [SyntaxAttr.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/SyntaxAttr.vim) to see if any other syntaxes override the region in question, but the tagged template literal (the `sql` word) has no syntax group attached to it.

The syntax in a Javascript file:

[image: screenshot(207)]

and the borked syntax in a identical Typescript file:

[image: screenshot(206)]

I've tried messing with the syntax region command (which essentially boils down to):

```
syntax region taggedTemplateStringSQL matchgroup=taggedTemplateTicks start=+sql`+ skip="\(\\`\|\${[^}]*`\|\(\<\K\k*\ze`[^`]*\)\)" end=+`+ keepend contains=@taggedTemplateContentSQL containedin=@jsExpression extend
```

but I've had no luck. There's just something different about the Typescript file syntax that I don't see.

here is the `init.vim` file I am using to debug:

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')
Plug 'cdata/vim-tagged-template'
Plug 'vim-scripts/SyntaxAttr.vim'
call plug#end()

let g:taggedtemplate#tagSyntaxMap = {
  \ "sql": "sql" }

autocmd FileType javascript,typescript : call taggedtemplate#applySyntaxMap()
```

running neovim:

```
NVIM v0.4.2
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
```